# Warning : no large blobs matching criteria found in packfiles - does the repo need to be packed?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

When running `bfg` I see:

```
Warning : no large blobs matching criteria found in packfiles - does the repo need to be packed?
```

How would I go about packing the repo?

Answer (score 13):

Run the garbage collector to repack the repository:

```
git gc
```

Credit:  [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/65#issuecomment-103418183).